# Is it safe to ignore the TypeError "TS2693: 'FieldPath' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I've run into a strange issue where if I import some Firebase types directly in my code I get "undefined is not an object" errors, but if I import them in an intermediary file and use them from there, then they work, so I have a firebaseTypes.ts file that looks like this:

```
import { FirebaseFirestoreTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { FirebaseStorageTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

export type NativeFirebaseError = ReactNativeFirebase.NativeFirebaseError;
export type TaskSnapshot = FirebaseStorageTypes.TaskSnapshot;
export type Reference = FirebaseStorageTypes.Reference;
export type DocumentChange = FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentChange;
export type SnapshotListenOptions = FirebaseFirestoreTypes.SnapshotListenOptions;
```

Now I'm trying to use FieldPath.documentId() in a query and hit an error trying to import FieldPath, so I add it to my `firebaseTypes.ts` document too:

`export type FieldPath = FirebaseFirestoreTypes.FieldPath;`

And in my `dao.ts` file I have a query that looks like this:

```
const fooIds: string[] = allFoo.map(f => f.fooId);
const updatedFoo: Foo[] | undefined = await db.collection<FirestoreFoo>(fooCollectionName)
        .where('userId', '==', uid)
        .where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', fooIds)
        .then(async (querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot) => {
            log.info('updateFooPhotos got a list of size: ', querySnapshot.size);
            return await processFooQuerySnapshot(querySnapshot, uid);
        }, (e) => {
           handleError(e, log);
           return undefined;
        });
```

This query runs successfully and gets me the results I want, but IntelliJ underlines `FieldPath` in red and gives the error "TS2693: 'FieldPath' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

I've tried modifying my import in firebaseTypes.ts but can't seem to make it work in a way that removes this error.

Is it safe to ignore it since my function is working? Or is there something else I should be doing to mitigate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `firebaseTypes.ts` FieldPath imports and exports to look like this and it fixed the issue:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const FieldPath = firestore.FieldPath;
export { FieldPath }
```